# Calculate day count without duplication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Suppose that web have below data:

```
Id  Start Date   End Date
1   2016-02-12   2016-02-19
2   2016-02-15   2016-02-22
3   2016-03-14   2016-03-20
4   2016-03-12   2016-03-22
```

I want to calculate day number without date duplication. 
For example 
for first row day count from start to end is 8 days
for second row day count from start to end is 8 days but it have 4 day overlap with first row and I don't want calculate it .
third row day count is ...

Comment: what the day number means? the difference from start and end or something else

Comment: Yes, exactly day number

Comment: Your question is not very clear. what do you mean by date duplication? Please post the desired output.

Comment: what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: Microsoft SQL SERVER 2012 or even 2014

Comment: What do you mean by you don't want to calculate it? Do you want to subtract the 4-day overlap? Or do you want to exclude that row from the result?

Comment: I want to exclude that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want the number of days for each row or just the total number of days, so I will show a way to get both options:

First, create and populate sample table:

```
DECLARE @Table as TABLE
(
    t_Id int identity(1,1),
    t_start date,
    t_end date
)

INSERT INTO @Table (t_start, t_end) VALUES
('2016-02-12', '2016-02-19'),
('2016-02-15', '2016-02-22'),
('2016-03-14', '2016-03-20'),
('2016-03-12', '2016-03-22')
```

Now, to get the sum of days for each row, leaving out the number of days that row overlaps with the previous row, you can do something like this:

Using a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [`LAG()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) window function to get the previous row's end date,
and using [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) to get the minimum date value if it's the first row:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t_Id, t_start, t_end, ISNULL(LAG(t_end) OVER (ORDER BY t_start), '0001-01-01') As prev_end
    FROM @Table 
)
```

Select from that CTE, using [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to see if the previous record overlaps the current one. if it does, subtract the number of overlapping days from the count:

```
SELECT  t_Id, 
        t_start, 
        t_end, 
        CASE WHEN prev_end < t_start THEN
            DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end)
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end) - DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, prev_end)
        END As number_of_days
FROM CTE
```

results:

```
t_Id        t_start    t_end      number_of_days
----------- ---------- ---------- --------------
1           2016-02-12 2016-02-19 7
2           2016-02-15 2016-02-22 3
4           2016-03-12 2016-03-22 10
3           2016-03-14 2016-03-20 -2 -- note that the prev row ends after this one.
```

To get the total number of days you can simply wrap the second query inside another cte and select `sum(number_of_days)`:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT t_Id, t_start, t_end, LAG(t_end) OVER (ORDER BY t_start) As prev_end
    FROM @Table 
), CTE2 As
(
    SELECT  t_Id, 
            t_start, 
            t_end, 
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(prev_end, '0001-01-01') < t_start THEN
                DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end)
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, t_end) - DATEDIFF(DAY, t_start, prev_end)

            END As number_of_days
    FROM CTE1
)

SELECT SUM(number_of_days) 
FROM CTE2
```

The result is 18.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any suggestion for EntityFramework?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration(startDate,endDate) VALUES('2007-05-06,'2007-05-07');
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,startDate,endDate) AS 'Duration' FROM dbo.WhatEver;
```

Returns: 1

Comment: I want day count off all row in table without any overlapping date (sorry for my bad english)